# what's proper class name for manager/browser/editor

Tags: object-oriented

I've read somewhere that it's a bad idea to name classes after verbs (manager/browser/editor)

but what's the proper name for manager/browser/editor?

EDIT:

the problem is that system could turn in a big ball of "services" - tiny objects which does something specific and does not contain any data - which is bad (at least because it just queries other objects)

but I also need to be able add new "managers" easily (right now app needs to manage users, ftp accounts, mail accounts, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main reason why names ending in `Manager` or `Browser` or `Editor` are sometimes bad is that they're vague and unspecific, and don't say enough about what the `FooManager` class is actually doing with `Foo`s.

For exactly that reason, there is no general answer to the question "what should they be replaced with?".

A class name should (so far as is possible given its brevity) say what an instance of the class does. If you really can't say anything more about what a `FooManager` does than that it manages `Foo`s, then call the class `FooManager` (and consider whether perhaps its respponsibilities should be divided among multiple other classes with better-focused responsibilities). If you can say something more specific, and you can do so briefly, then that should indicate what name would be better.

(Of course if your class is called `WebBrowser` or `TextEditor` or `SeniorManager` then none of the above applies; that isn't the sort of thing the folklore about not giving classes that sort of name is aimed at. :-) )

Comment: so UserManager, MailAccountsManager, etc. are all ok?
I was also thinking to factor some functionality together in their modules (UserModule - users, payments, MailModule - mail accs, mail aliases) and use dynamic adapters to attach them in the rest of system. - like AppSection(callback) where callback would point directly to some method on module

Comment: It might be better to find something more informative than, say, `UserManager` (which is pretty vague about exactly what instances of the class are doing). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866794/naming-classes-how-to-avoid-calling-everything-a-whatevermanager for an earlier discussion of this.

Comment: interesting discussion - thx for the link. Is then MailModule better idea (including CRUD for all mail entities?) - still it smells like duplication (add_mailaccount, add_mailalias, add_xxx)

Comment: `MailModule` doesn't feel great to me either, but of course I haven't seen the rest of your system!

Comment: A-ha :-) `closer the program models the real world problem, the better the program will be.` - so the right object should be application, right? because it does all of the work

Comment: Application is useful as a root object for an Application, but only when the namespace describes what that application is. Certainly Module is much more vague than manager... Try this... what does it do? Now summarise that, if it does many things, it's a manager, and it should only manage objects of one category, so if it's managing users, it's a UserManager, and you would ideally composite specific user functions into the UserManager as separate classes, utilising Composition/Strategy pattern.

Answer (score 6):

"Manager", "Browser", and "Editor" are nouns, not verbs.  "Manage", "Browse", and "Edit" are verbs, and not particularly good class names!

Comment: read edit why it's bad